# Python class recording attributes without specifying self ?

Tags: python, class, attributes, blender

I have a question regarding a Python class I use in Blender. Basically, I wonder how the class works because some attributes are recorded without me specifically writing `self.value = something`. Here's the code:

```
class DialogOperator(bpy.types.Operator):

    bl_idname = "object.dialog_operator"
    bl_label = "Save/Load animation"

    saving = bpy.props.BoolProperty(name="Save ? Else load.")
    path_to_anim = bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Path to folder")
    anim_name = bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Animation name:")
    # path_to_anim += "/home/mehdi/Blender/Scripts/"

    def execute(self, context):
        # print('This is execute with: Saving: {}  Name:{}'.format(self.saving, self.path_to_anim))

        if self.saving: 
            self.launch_save()
            message = 'Animation {} saved at {}'.format(self.anim_name, self.path_to_anim)
        else: 
            self.launch_load()
            message = 'Animation {} loaded'.format(self.anim_name)

        self.report({'INFO'}, message)

        return {'FINISHED'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        wm = context.window_manager
        return wm.invoke_props_dialog(self)

    def launch_load(self): 
        full_path = self.path_to_anim + self.anim_name
        target_armature = Humanoid(bpy.data.objects['Armature'])
        load_all(full_path, target_armature, 'LastLoaded')

    def launch_save(self): 

        full_path = self.path_to_anim + self.anim_name
        source_armature = Humanoid(bpy.data.objects['Armature'])
        curves = source_armature.get_curves()
        save_all(curves, source_armature,full_path)
```

Now, how come `saving`, `path_to_anim` and `anim_name` are considered as attributes (I'm able to call them in `execute()` and `launch()`) even though I did not write `self.saving = saving`

Thanks !

Comment: They are defined at class level, outside of any methods, so they are class attributes.

Comment: self check if the attribute in the instance then in the class

Comment: They are class properties so that the values can be specified before the operator is run. [This answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/14493/935) explains their use a bit more and might help make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `saving`,`path_to_anim` and `anim_name` are class attributes. They are defined for the class and not for a particular instance. They are shared among the instances. Here is a link for further explanation [class-instance-attributes-python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/class-instance-attributes-python/)